# Training an object detection model on custom data images missing labels for other objects in the dataset. Is it possible?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I am working on creating an object detection model that should be able to look at an image (and later watch a video) and label particular objects inside the image. However, in one dataset of "gun", "officer"s and "gun" are the two objects labelled, and if things like batons or riot shields happen to be inside the image they aren't labelled. There is however separate datasets for "riot shield" and "baton"s, because these are objects I want to detect. Equally, these two datasets happen to sometimes have guns inside them that aren't labelled etc etc because they were collected only to recognize those individual objects.

Here is my question:

If I train the model on these datasets, and it is training on the "gun" dataset for example, and see's unlabelled riot shields, will those unlabelled objects in those images conflict with the labelled images when it trains on "riot shield"s and ruin the detection? If so, is there a way to isolate it's training so it doesn't make assumptions about other objects that are unlabelled in images?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem if an object shows up unlabled in a picture. The network is being given conflicting messages about what is and isn't a certain object. AFAIK there's no real way to isolate training. However, you can train on the gun dataset first and then have it run through and label all the guns in the other datasets. The same idea should work for each object you want to detect in other datasets.